# Swap function and emoji key in microsoft designer keyboard

Tags: keyboard, microsoft

I'd like to swap the function and emoji key in microsoft designer keyboard. Has anyone been able to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know which OS you're using, `xmodmap` might be what you're looking for. Here are some resources:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmodmap

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=x-xmodmap-command